# libstdc++ library not loaded on Mac OS X Lion (10.7.2)

Tags: macos, osx-lion, c++

I recently updated my Mac, running Mac OS X Lion (10.7.2) with some EFI Firmware Updates. Since then, certain applications (Pages, Keynote, and Google Chrome for me) don't load. The error Apple is giving me is that the libstdc++ library isn't being loaded.

I was also recently attempting to install GCC on my system (because apparently it wasn't already installed even though I have Xcode). It may be that the EFI Firmware update is just a coincident, since I was working on GCC at around the same time.

Also, I don't have Time Machine set up, so I can't restore from a pervious version.

Here are the details I get from the OS about the issue:

```
Process:         Pages [512]
Path:            /Applications/Pages.app/Contents/MacOS/Pages
Identifier:      com.apple.iWork.Pages
Version:         4.1 (923)
Build Info:      iWorkAppBundler-9500000~129
App Item ID:     409201541
App External ID: 3911467
Code Type:       X86 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [136]

Date/Time:       2011-11-06 20:32:14.676 -0500
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.7.2 (11C74)
Report Version:  9

Interval Since Last Report:          361 sec
Crashes Since Last Report:           1
Per-App Crashes Since Last Report:   1
Anonymous UUID:                      1720C88A-EAEB-41C4-9742-82FC843F2E4A

Crashed Thread:  0

Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000002, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
dyld: launch, loading dependent libraries

Dyld Error Message:
  Library not loaded: /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
  Referenced from: /Applications/Pages.app/Contents/MacOS/Pages
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture
    /usr/local/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture
    /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture

Binary Images:
    0x1000 -   0x345fe8  com.apple.iWork.Pages (4.1 - 923) <CA075805-8E22-2F83-8911-ED378A10FA8D> /Applications/Pages.app/Contents/MacOS/Pages
  0x3cc000 -   0x44aff7  com.apple.iLifeMediaBrowser (2.6.1 - 502.1.5) <15323460-62E8-39BC-ACF0-E0C3A916C994> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/iLifeMediaBrowser.framework/Versions/A/iLifeMediaBrowser
  0x48c000 -   0xf76fe6 +SFCompatibility (??? - ???) <EB5B1E17-8037-6AA9-F2C9-FBBE7E937C77> /Applications/Pages.app/Contents/Frameworks/SFCompatibility.framework/Versions/A/SFCompatibility
 0x16b4000 -  0x2142ffe  com.apple.AppKit (6.7.2 - 1138.23) <ADFA8D70-601E-3B5C-96FD-F45F52055CC8> /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/AppKit
 0x26d0000 -  0x26d0ff0  com.apple.ApplicationServices (41 - 41) <BED33E1D-C95C-3654-9A3A-0CB3607F9F10> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/ApplicationServices
 0x26d8000 -  0x28aefe3  com.apple.CoreFoundation (6.7.1 - 635.15) <AC9F6462-6315-3D89-8075-D048DB4DBF7E> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation
 0x29ce000 -  0x2cd8ff3  com.apple.Foundation (6.7.1 - 833.20) <B5092554-485A-3A7D-904B-B04B1EE5C50C> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/C/Foundation
 0x2e34000 -  0x30e3ff7  com.apple.AddressBook.framework (6.1 - 1062) <8992D5C7-DC3C-3009-8A9E-A6937B91BB4D> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/Versions/A/AddressBook
 0x322d000 -  0x3274fff  com.apple.SystemConfiguration (1.11.1 - 1.11) <CA6CE2B6-DC18-31FF-9668-70BB2FD8D7BB> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/Versions/A/SystemConfiguration
 0x3296000 -  0x32afffe  com.apple.Keynote.sfstyles (1.0 - 1.0) <04155064-D014-1931-ABFA-DF59242DA6AD> /Applications/Pages.app/Contents/Frameworks/SFStyles.framework/Versions/A/SFStyles
 0x32c1000 -  0x3771ff5  com.apple.SFTabular (1.0 - 1.0) <F9702F15-C061-C11B-9394-4248E8D036F8> /Applications/Pages.app/Contents/Frameworks/SFTabular.framework/Versions/A/SFTabular
 0x3944000 -  0x39f8ff7  com.apple.Keynote.sfutility (1.0 - 0.0.1d1) <E50E9C04-742E-62AC-C9D5-54E4B36F3FFF> /Applications/Pages.app/Contents/Frameworks/SFUtility.framework/Versions/A/SFUtility
 0x3a6b000 -  0x3bfbff2  com.apple.Keynote.sfdrawables (2.0 - 2.0) <2FC7BAFF-5247-C3D5-2228-4253A0E2393A> /Applications/Pages.app/Contents/Frameworks/SFDrawables.framework/Versions/A/SFDrawables
 0x3cbd000 -  0x3f2afef +SFWordProcessing (??? - ???) <9DC85FBF-7E60-8310-5DD3-2F2E606C342D> /Applications/Pages.app/Contents/Frameworks/SFWordProcessing.framework/Versions/A/SFWordProcessing
 0x4054000 -  0x409eff4  com.apple.Keynote.SFControls (1.0 - 20030306_1) <EB3E250D-AFC4-BD31-282D-0FA34045CC77> /Applications/Pages.app/Contents/Frameworks/SFControls.framework/Versions/A/SFControls
 0x40cd000 -  0x4125fef  com.apple.Keynote.sfarchiving (1.0 - 0.0.1d1) <B95B1C43-A55C-8101-E314-3AF962899CBD> /Applications/Pages.app/Contents/Frameworks/SFArchiving.framework/Versions/A/SFArchiving
 0x4159000 -  0x4266feb  com.apple.Keynote.sfrendering (1.0 - 1.0) <38739A0B-606A-DBEE-839E-2046C04AA4D3> /Applications/Pages.app/Contents/Frameworks/SFRendering.framework/Versions/A/SFRendering
 0x42cd000 -  0x4355ff9  com.apple.Keynote.proofreader (0 - 1) <F57878B8-7670-F608-394E-6B59C3E930A3> /Applications/Pages.app/Contents/Frameworks/SFProofReader.framework/Versions/A/SFProofReader
 0x4365000 -  0x4365fff  com.apple.Carbon (153 - 153) <6FF98F0F-2CDE-3888-A304-4ED447D24CE3> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Carbon
 0x4368000 -  0x4420ffe  com.apple.Keynote.sfinspectors (1.0 - 1.0) <35D792D0-BCD4-D335-6C11-A21A74AB4F6F> /Applications/Pages.app/Contents/Frameworks/SFInspectors.framework/Versions/A/SFInspectors
 0x4480000 -  0x47e3ffa  com.apple.Keynote.sfcharts (2.0 - 2.0) <9B912294-3C25-064B-F3A7-12A10830CC3B> /Applications/Pages.app/Contents/Frameworks/SFCharts.framework/Versions/A/SFCharts
 0x4a1d000 -  0x4a62feb  com.apple.Keynote.SFAnimation (1.0 - 0.0.1d1) <D56A94CC-C5F8-399F-5FA9-B9F1AA6A08B3> /Applications/Pages.app/Contents/Frameworks/SFAnimation.framework/Versions/A/SFAnimation
 0x4a91000 -  0x4abbffb  com.apple.Keynote.sflicense (1.0 - 0.0.1d1) <02E0BCE8-2712-549D-8C11-BFCC1C369D71> /Applications/Pages.app/Contents/Frameworks/SFLicense.framework/Versions/A/SFLicense
 0x4ad9000 -  0x4ae7fff  com.apple.opengl (1.7.5 - 1.7.5) <81166D23-DE8E-3938-AAD3-29B1FA5E446E> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/OpenGL
 0x4aef000 -  0x4bd7fff  libxml2.2.dylib (10.3.0 - compatibility 10.0.0) <ED3F5E83-8C76-3D46-B2FF-0D5BDF8970C5> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
 0x4bfb000 -  0x4d5dfff  com.apple.QTKit (7.7.1 - 2306) <5A7E5ED0-C4DC-3CEC-ABE0-24899134ACE1> /System/Library/Frameworks/QTKit.framework/Versions/A/QTKit
 0x4e27000 -  0x50acfe3  com.apple.QuickTime (7.7.1 - 2306) <F8C64DC4-3FE4-3A06-B10B-59E7F3BA6FDD> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuickTime.framework/Versions/A/QuickTime
 0x5155000 -  0x5206ff8  com.apple.sf.sfapplication (1.0 - 1.0) <F02A8B95-CBE3-BE65-9CF3-9EE59A47C068> /Applications/Pages.app/Contents/Frameworks/SFApplication.framework/Versions/A/SFApplication
 0x526e000 -  0x526efff  com.apple.quartzframework (1.5 - 1.5) <EF66BF08-620E-3D11-87D4-35D0B0CD1F6D> /System/Library/Frameworks/Quartz.framework/Versions/A/Quartz
0x3f000000 - 0x3f425fee +org.coin3d.Coin.framework (3.0.0a - 3.0.0a) /Applications/Pages.app/Contents/Frameworks/Inventor.framework/Versions/C/Inventor
0x8fe2a000 - 0x8fe5c9c7  dyld (195.5 - ???) <134323A7-49DC-3A9D-ACFD-32FAD0FD6BA2> /usr/lib/dyld
0x9031d000 - 0x9032bfff  libz.1.dylib (1.2.5 - compatibility 1.0.0) <E73A4025-835C-3F73-9853-B08606E892DB> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib

Model: MacBookPro8,1, BootROM MBP81.0047.B24, 2 processors, Intel Core i7, 2.7 GHz, 4 GB, SMC 1.68f96
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 3000, Intel HD Graphics 3000, Built-In, 384 MB
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 2 GB, DDR3, 1333 MHz, 0x80CE, 0x4D34373142353737334448302D4348392020
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 2 GB, DDR3, 1333 MHz, 0x80CE, 0x4D34373142353737334448302D4348392020
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0xD6), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (5.100.98.75.18)
Bluetooth: Version 4.0.1f4, 2 service, 18 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en1
Serial ATA Device: TOSHIBA MK5065GSXF, 500.11 GB
Serial ATA Device: OPTIARC DVD RW AD-5970H
USB Device: FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in), apple_vendor_id, 0x8509, 0xfa200000 / 3
USB Device: hub_device, 0x0424  (SMSC), 0x2513, 0xfa100000 / 2
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad, apple_vendor_id, 0x0252, 0xfa120000 / 5
USB Device: BRCM2070 Hub, 0x0a5c  (Broadcom Corp.), 0x4500, 0xfa110000 / 4
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller, apple_vendor_id, 0x821a, 0xfa113000 / 8
USB Device: hub_device, 0x0424  (SMSC), 0x2513, 0xfd100000 / 2
USB Device: IR Receiver, apple_vendor_id, 0x8242, 0xfd110000 / 3
```

Comment: What exact Mac do you have?

Comment: Early 2011 Macbook Pro running OS X 10.7.2

Answer (score 3):

I solved the problem by reinstalling the OS.

To reinstall the OS, restart the computer. As it's turning on hold Command-R. When a window asking what language you want comes up, let go. Select your language. Click "Reinstall Mac OS X Lion". Click Continue. Make sure your connected to the internet. It will begin downloading the OS, and it may take several hours for this to finish.

When it turns on again, everything should be working fine, and all of your files will stay pretty much unharmed and unchanged (except if you made some changes to the OS).

Another recommendation I have (which I am now doing) is constant Time Machine backups, especially if changing something that may affect the OS.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that you installed gcc in `/usr`. I had the same problem.

Comment: Welcome to super user! Your answer is a bit short, see the FAQ of this site.

Answer (score 0):

You installed gcc in /usr, which clobbered system libraries like `/usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib`
(like @chao chao said).

Reinstalling the entire OS is the nuclear option.